# limit points in lower limit topology

Tags: general-topology

Let W = [1,2) ⋃ [4,5] ⋃ (7,8] and consider ℝ with the lower limit topology.
How do I know what the limit points are in this problem.

I am thinking that they are 5, 7 and 8 but I am not sure with this being in lower limit topology.

Answer (score 1):

Only one of those numbers is a limit point of $W$, and you’ve missed infinitely many limit points.

A point $x\in\Bbb R$ is a limit point of $W$ if every open nbhd of $x$ contains at least one point of $W$ **other than** $x$ itself. In practice this means that $x$ is a limit point of $W$ if for each $\epsilon>0$, $[x,x+\epsilon)$ contains at least one point of $W$ other than $x$. And that in turn is equivalent to requiring that $(x,x+\epsilon)\cap W\ne\varnothing$ for each $\epsilon>0$. (Why?)

Now clearly $(5,6)\cap W=\varnothing$, so $5$ is not a limit point of $W$. And $(1,1+\epsilon)\cap W\ne\varnothing$ for each $\epsilon>0$, so $1$ **is** a limit point of $W$.

See if you can use the discussion and examples above to come up with a better answer.